# Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined error with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a plain markup code like below

```
<ListItemText title={details} />
```

My application is using typescript, and its giving error at `title={details}` like

> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined error with TypeScript

How to correct it? What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: I suppose that in one place you set `details = null` or you define it as `const details: string | null`?

Comment: Ensure that `details` can't be `null`, only a string or `undefined`.

Comment: @johannchopin Yes, its as you said, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply give an placeholder for the null value...
**CODE**

```
<ListItemText title={details??""} />
```

It will only check if the value is nullish instead of checking falsy(`null, undefined, NAN, ""`), don't mix with `||` or operator. If `details` is null, then it will pass the empty string (which is eventually a string type) to the prop..

Comment: This works but writing code like that make TypeScript worthless.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to match the types of both input & output & you havn't mentioned  your types. Try avoiding this method in TS. Just match the both of the types or add null type to `details` prop by doing `details?: string | null ` in your prop type defination, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that the `title` prop need a type `string | undefined`. So (as [CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871033/cherrydt) mentioned) you need to be sure that `details` will always be from the same type as `title`.

You just need to declare it:

```js
const details: string | undefined = ...
```

Then in you case you will probably have another error because you assign `null` to  `details`. If this is the case just assign `undefined` instead of `null`.